# Bookshelf Association Error

Tags: mysql, associations, bookshelf.js

I am trying to create associations and use those associations to create queries, but I keep receiving this error:

[Stack Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHifq.png)

Here is the file with my models and query. (test.js)

```
import knex from 'knex';
import {
    client,
    host,
    user,
    password,
    database,
    charset
} from './environment/dev';
import bookshelf from 'bookshelf';

const Knex = knex({
    client: client,
    connection: {
        host: host,
        user: user,
        password: password,
        database: database,
        charset: charset
    }
});
const Bookshelf = bookshelf(Knex);
Bookshelf.plugin('registry');

const AccessGroup = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'AccessGroup',
    idAttribute: 'idAccessGroup',
    users: () => {
        return this.hasMany('User');
    }
});

const User = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'User',
    idAttribute: 'idUser',
    accessGroup: () => {
        return this.belongsTo('AccessGroup', 'idAccessGroup');
    }
});

const checkUserExist = (userName) => {
    // return new User({
    //     userName
    // }).fetch({withRelated:['accessGroup']});
    return User.forge({userName}).fetch({withRelated: ['accessGroup']});
    // return User.fetchAll({withRelated: ['accessGroup']});
    // return new User({userName}).accessGroup();
}

export { checkUserExist };
```

Basically I have issues with using these associations. I am able to run basic queries on my models and receive accurate data from my database. All of my idAttributes are correct as well as table names. I've looked extensively online but cannot find anything that helps.

When I perform a basic query,

```
new User({
    userName: 'admin8791'
}).fetch().then(d => {
    console.log(d);
});
```

The results state that there is not relation.

```
ModelBase {
  attributes:
   { userName: 'admin8791',
     idUser: 8791,
     firstName: 'Jerrell',
     lastName: 'Jones',
     idAccessGroup: 1 },
  _previousAttributes:
   { userName: 'admin8791',
     idUser: 8791,
     firstName: 'Jerrell',
     lastName: 'Jones',
     idAccessGroup: 1 },
  changed: {},
  relations: {},
  cid: 'c1',
  _knex: null }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to eager load the associations:

```
new User({
  userName: 'admin8791'
}).fetch({withRelated: 'accessGroup'}).then(d => {
  console.log(d);
});
```